# How can I sort files based on their last updated time using "dir" command in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I am using "dir" command on the command line prompt in Windows 10. I've tried the following:

```
c:\my_folder> dir /s /b
```

but, the above command is not displaying the files according to the last updated time of files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open a [powershell console](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sv38GGoPcoI) and enter this command:

```
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime
```

If you want descending order, then use:

```
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending
```

Comment: Thanks @krokodilko, I've slightly modified the above command for my usage: 

Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | where {!$_.PsIsC
ontainer} | Select-Object Name | clip

Comment: OMG. I have to type all _that_? As opposed to "ls -lrt"? What kind of operating system from hell is this?